# How to create a Custom UIAlertView in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have an iphone app and on a button click it should open a custom alert view by showing some text and "X" cross sign on the top right Window as we have in lightbox in any web application.

Comment: do you want to customize uialertview's buttons?

Comment: yes i want to customize them to fit out side the border and look like popview in websites

Comment: what is your need is not clear from your question.Do u want to open a view in the button click with a close button on the top left.then u have not to use alertview.just use a view with your design and hide it when the view is loading and in the buttonclick unhide the view ..thats it coool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is link i think it can solve your problem.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-uialertview-custom-graphics/

Comment: @jamil what if my versionis below 6 ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement Customize alert View
then You should this sample Code that have very attractive alert views collection with the help of ViewController.
Try this sample Code link
https://github.com/eaigner/CODialog

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example how to create your own class that acts similar to alert view, but you can put any background/button graphics you want:

http://iosdevtricks.blogspot.com/2013/04/creating-custom-alert-view-for-iphone.html

Comment: That is exactly why given example subclasses UIView

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView; 
- (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView;
```

in any of the above message, check the subviews and their class and change the values as you desire. see this sample code for UIActionSheet. search for classes of all components using ns log and customize your desire class. This is uiactionsheet code

```
for (UIView* view in [actionSheet subviews])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",[view class]);
        if ([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UIAlertButton"] && [view respondsToSelector:@selector(setAlpha:)])
        {
            [view setAlpha:2.0];
            [view setOpaque:YES];
            if ([view respondsToSelector:@selector(title)])
            {
                NSString* title = [view performSelector:@selector(title)];
                if ([title isEqualToString:@"Cancel"] && [view respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forState:)] && [view respondsToSelector:@selector(setFrame:)] && [view respondsToSelector:@selector(setFrame:)] && [view respondsToSelector:@selector(setTitleColor:forState:)])
                {

                    [view setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    [view setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-cancel.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y+10, view.frame.size.width,view.frame.size.height)];

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i did not get this can you explain me more

Comment: look. ios has layers on each view. you have to search out each layer on the screen and then check whcih class it has. e.g. an alert has a lable, a button, and a button further has a label etc. when you have found your destination class like button, then you can change it's behaviour

Answer (score 0):

**Create custom view in ReturnAlert.xib**

[image]

```
class ReturnView: UIView, UITextFieldDelegate {


}

class ReturnAlert: UIAlertController {
   var returnView: ReturnView?

   public convenience init(id message: String?) {
      self.init(title: nil, message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)

      guard let view = UINib(nibName: "ReturnAlert", bundle: Bundle(for: ReturnView.self)).instantiate(withOwner: ReturnView.self, options: nil)[0] as? ReturnView else{
        fatalError("Return view not found")
    }

    self.returnView = view
    view.alert = self
    let parent = self.view.subviews[0].subviews[0]

    for sv in parent.subviews {
        sv.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    view.bounds = CGRect(x: parent.bounds.origin.x, y: parent.bounds.origin.y, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)

    parent.addSubview(view)

    let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: parent, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: parent, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    parent.addConstraint(xConstraint)
    parent.addConstraint(yConstraint)
  }
}
```