# Display and mange Multiple UITextField, UILabel and UIButton in UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I am new to IOS, I need to display multiple labels, textfields and button in alert view. Here is sample screenshot.

[image: screenshot for multiple textfield and label]

Comment: Create a popup view by your own! No need to manage this things in alretview!

Comment: you can also use custom alertviews http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782434/how-to-create-a-custom-uialertview-in-iphone-app

Comment: k i try in popup view @AshishKakkad

Comment: You can't customize `UIAlertView`. You have do design your own component. There are several examples about doing your own alert view on SO, CocoaControls, GitHub, CocoaPods if you are looking for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is better to Design UIView as per your requiremnt and add the UIView To Apllication KeyWindow with animation, hide and show that view with animation